# Constructor Injecting Container in StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

Is it valid to inject a Container via a constructor? Or does it need to be more granular?

```
public class Car{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public Car(IContainer container){
        this._container = container;
    }

    public string DoSomething(){
        var service1 =_container.GetInstance<IServiceINeed1>();
        service1.DoStuff();

        var service2 =_container.GetInstance<IServiceINeed2>();
        service2.DoThings();
    }
}
```

Vs.

```
public class Car{
    private readonly IServiceINeed1 _service1;
    private readonly IServiceINeed2 _service2;

    public Car(IServiceINeed1 service1, IServiceINeed2 service2){
        this._service1 = service1;
        this._service2 = service2;
    }

public string DoSomething(){
        this._service1.DoStuff();
        this._service2.DoThings();
    }
}
```

If it is invalid, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: I do not see what the problem is.You define some behaviour into your interfaces.You inject implementations in the  and then you just use them in your services that need them.

Comment: Multiple issues here. If car represents and data entity, it should not have any dependency. Also container should not be injected, container should be resolving the dependencies for other classes.

Comment: I wasn't putting much attention to the class name. Let's say it is called SpecialService instead. Also, what would be the reason behind forbidden container injection?

Answer (score 0):

If you inject Container then you don't have a clear picture on what dependencies your class depend on. I think this is called Service Locator and you can read [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) 
why is an Service Locator an Anti-Pattern. So its better if you inject interfaces that your class depends on.